# Websocket upgrade response not reaching client through Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a IOS/swift client connecting to a NodeJS/ws websocket service through a NGINX reverse proxy. All the websocket related forwarding setup is done in the NGINX configuration and websocket service is able to upgrade and setup the websocket connection from the client's upgrade request.

But on the client end, no Response is received for the original http upgrade Request.

When the websocket terminates the connection after a timeout, the client gets the Response, which is strange.

The NGINX reverse proxy is running in a container on a VM.

I have seen one other question to the exact same issue but did not find any answers. Is this a problem with the proxy running in a container?

"[Nginx not passing websocket upgrade response back to client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30718771/nginx-not-passing-websocket-upgrade-response-back-to-client)"

Here is the snippet of my nginx proxy.

```
server {
listen       443 ssl;
server_name  <hidden>;
ssl          on;
ssl_certificate     /etc/certs/<hidden>.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/certs/<hidden>.pem;
ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

location ~^/(?<cluster>[^/]+)/websocket {
    proxy_pass https://<hidden>
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    set $http_upgrade "websocket";
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header FromRP      <hidden>;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-Addr $remote_addr:$remote_port;
    proxy_set_header X-External-URL   $scheme://$host$request_uri ;
    proxy_read_timeout           360;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/websocket.access.log upstreamlog;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/websocket.error.log info;
    proxy_buffers 8 32k;
    proxy_buffer_size 64k;
}
```

}

Comment: can you post your NGINX configuration

Comment: Added the nginx config to the post. Also went through wireshark, and found that the websocket service does return the upgraded response back to the RP but RP does not forward it back to the client. This works when accessing the RP from an internal network, and we can see the RP forwarding to the client.  But accessing the RP from an external network has this issue.

Comment: Solved : nginx does proxy buffering, and it is on by default. I set proxy_buffering off;  in location{} for websocket. It works now.